# Show that the graph of the equation $x^{3}+3 x^{2} y+3 x y^{2}+y^{3}-x^{2}+y^{2}=0$ is a union of line and a parabola.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Show that the graph of the equation $$x^{3}+3 x^{2} y+3 x y^{2}+y^{3}-x^{2}+y^{2}=0$$ is a union of line and a parabola.

This seems a pretty easy question, but the answer I got is not matching with the claim made in the question.

Here's how I solved the problem:

The idenitity $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$ makes the problem easy. We then have, $(x+y)^3-x^2+y^2=0.$ Now, if $x+y=1$, then we can write, $(x+y)^3-x^2+y^2=0,$ implies $1-x^2+y^2=0$ which means, $x^2-y^2=1$ and this is the equation of a rectangular hyperbola and $x+y=1$ is a straight line equation.

But I am  unable to find how this equation is the union of a line and a parabola. It would be much helpful if someone points out where is the mistake in my solution.

Comment: Neither the graph of $x+y=1$ nor the graph of $x^2-y^2=1$ is a subset of the graph of this equation.

Comment: Have you graphed this to look at it?  Or are you trying to do it without a graph?  As @MishaLavrov mentioned, you will see the line is not $x+y=1$ and it will give you a very quick way to figuring out what the equation of the line should be.

Comment: Use the binomial formula, $-x^2+y^2=(-x+y)(x+y)$.

Comment: We have $p(x,-x)=0$ if $p(x,y)=x^{3}+3 x^{2} y+3 x y^{2}+y^{3}-x^{2}+y^{2}$. Hence the line $x+y=0$ is included in the graph of $p(x,y)=0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov But where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\color{blue}{x^{3}+3 x^{2} y+3 x y^{2}+y^{3}}-x^{2}+y^{2}=\color{blue}{(x+y)^3}-(x+y)(x-y)=$$

$$=(x+y)\left[\color{blue}{(x+y)^2}+(x-y)\right]=0$$

and with respect to the orthogonal directions $u=x+y=0$ and $v=x-y=0$

$$(x+y)^2+(x-y)=0 \iff v=-u^2$$

which is indeed a parabola.

---

The mistake you are doing is that you are just plugging $x+y=1$ into the original equation which is another thing (i.e. an intersection).

Here we are requested to factor the given expression $f(x,y)=l(x,y)\cdot p(x,y)=0$ such that $l(x,y)=0$ is a line and $p(x,y)=0$ is a parabola, that is $$f(x,y)=l(x,y)\cdot p(x,y)=0 \iff l(x,y)=0 \; \lor\; p(x,y)=0$$

---

Here is a [plot by WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20x%5E3%2B3%20x%5E2%20y%2B3%20x%20y%5E2%2By%5E3-x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D0%20for%20x%3D-4..4%2C%20y%3D-4..4)

[image]

Comment: Please explain the mistake I made.

Comment: @StephenSmith I've added the detailed explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show the absurdity of what you did: Suppose you have the equation $x+y=2$ instead and you substitute $x+y=1$ in your equation. Then you get $1=2$ which is absurd.

Furthermore, if you substitute $x+y=1$ in your equation then you have to substitute also $y=1-x$ getting $2-2x=0.$ So, $x=1$ and $y=0$. That means $(1,0)$ is the intersection of the graph of your equation $(x+y)^3-x^2+y^2=0$ and the line $x+y=1.$